# Pasting Cell Color with VBA using vlookup reference

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on code for creating an org chart and want the ability to have the color of the source cell in a table to be pasted in the org chart. Currently the destination cell format is being driven from a pre-set format ("chartformat"). Code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
' Put Preformula

Range("preformula").Copy
Range("finalarea").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Org Chart").Calculate

' Clear Blanks

Range("finalarea").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 4).ClearContents

' Put Format

Range("chartformat").Copy
Range("finalarea").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats


' Put Formula and Clear

Range("chartformula").Copy
Range("finalarea").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Sheets("Org Chart").Calculate

Range("finalarea").Copy
Range("finalarea").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pasting formats after pasting formulas?

```
Range("chartformula").Copy
Range("finalarea").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Range("finalarea").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Sheets("Org Chart").Calculate
```

You should also qualify the `Range` with a sheet, *especially* since your macro is not limited to just one sheet.